# How to hide column based on condition

Tags: sql, hide, conditional-statements

Im newbie in sql and i want to  filter results of a select statement.I would like to hide the value of specific column in case of a specific value in another column(same row).
For example i want the Products.product column to be hidden or empty in case that the value in the Products.active column is false :
Thanks in advance

```
SELECT Products.product,Products.Active,
CASE Products.product
 WHEN  'false' THEN Products.Active = '' 
END          
FROM Products
```

Comment: The column cannot be hidden. You can make it empty/null/with bad data. But with just 1 query you cannot dynamically hide a column

Comment: Thanks, if i want to make it  empty could you please be more specific on how can i do  this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Products.Active,
CASE Products.Active
 WHEN  'false' THEN  '' 
 ELSE  Products.product
END  AS 'HIDDEN COLUMN'
FROM Products
```

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to eliminate that entire record using the `WHERE` clause instead of `CASE`. If you do want the record and just want this field empty use the following `CASE` statement:

```
CASE Products.Active
    WHEN false
    THEN null
    ELSE Products.product
END
```